# ipad split view using existing view controllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, ipad

I have a storyboard - a tableview leading to a detail view - and the layout works for iPhone. I now want to create a separate storyboard for iPad which is a split view showing the same table as iPhone on the left (master) and same detail on the right. 
I have tried: adding a new storyboard, dragging a splitview, making rootVC class for master and detailVC class for detail, turning app to universal, placing iPad storyboard name in box. Also, the same named outlets are connected. But when I run the screen is black. 
What am I missing?

I'm running xcode 6 and using OBJ c. I want to create a separate storyboard rather than meddle with constraints as I feel it's more within my capability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stupid question but does your iPad storyboard have the UISplitViewController set as the initial View Controller?

Comment: Thank you. Silly oversight on my part